# Google Sheets Query aggregate function grouping on variable dates

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to get the sum of the monthly net balance of worked hours for the employees (PID) over a period of time specified in another column (Settlement Date). It is not that easy to explain but this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mRXyJ79vPKsnSpWzn_dbPMM55WjRkA_LqtSoKw4DTXw/edit?usp=sharing) should be self-explanatory. Please note that cells F3 and O3 contain query formula.

Any thoughts? Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the expected outcome? And can you provide information on what you shared till now?

Comment: @lamblichus I'm looking to have a correct formula to get the expected hours on the Case 2 table. In case 1, the Settlement Date is the same for all PID's but in Case 2, each PID has it's own Settlement date. My query formula in O3 gives the sum of worked hours for each PID but they are not all correct. the correct ones are given in column R.  It seems the grouping for all PIDs are done on the total rows selected for the firs PID in the group...

Comment: ... For example, for P102, the settlement date is 31/12/2020; the Activity Date for this is on row 16 (a total of 13 rows. If you take the total sum of the hours for P103 over the first 13 rows it equals the calculated result (-17.5859); whereas the Settlement Date is 31/01/2021 and the sum of hours should be over 14 rows (-19.4090).  I hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You are not comparing the dates in `Col3` and `Col4` appropriately.

#### Solution:

- You can compare `Col3` and `Col4` directly, as shown here:

```
=query({J3:M},
       "select Col1,sum(Col2),Col4
        where Col1 is not null
          and Col3<=Col4
        group by Col1,Col4
        label sum(Col2) 'Calculated Hours' ",1)
```

[image]

Comment: So simple and I was playing with date comparison!! Many thanks.